# Flutter Stack / Align

Tags: flutter, alignment

Align inside a stack gives me a result that I do not understand.

Here is the code:

```
    Container(
      height: totalHeight,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: avatarSize,
              height: avatarSize,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: imageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: 35,
                height: 20,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The yellow container is always appearing at the bottom left, no matter what I do.
I want to have it in the bottom center.

avatarSize is greater than 35 of course. I put an outer container to let the stack expand to that outer parent. Seems all natural, but not working. Weird.

What do I miss here?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: The problem is not with this code, it may be in the parent widget, Share the full code with us so we can help you

Comment: @faroukosama it is really the parent widget, when I set the width of the container to a avatarSize it works as well. Still I am puzzled why the parent widget should affect an align in a stack that has a well defined center. There must be a reason but I do not understand it.

Answer (score -1):

The best widget to align something inside a Stack is the Positioned widget. I think it can solve your problem

[Positioned Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgtPleVwxBQ)

Comment: Actually I know this widget but the advantage of the Align is that it allows to to perfectly center two widgets, with positioned you need to know the size, which you sometimes just don't know. For that reason Align is the way to go.